# Bad attempt to problem without use of Archimedean Property

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I want to prove, without using Archimedean property, that for each $x>0$, there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<x$

My “attempt” to proof was:

Suppose, by contradiction, that there exists $x>0$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\frac{1}{n}\geq{x}$.

Then, because $x>0$ and $n>0$, we have $\frac{1}{x}\geq{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. That means $\frac{1}{x}\geq{1}$

How can I follow?

I tried also by proving $Ínf(\frac{1}{x})=0$. My attempt was:

1. Clarly, we have $x>0$ and $1>0$, so $\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x>0$, and so, $0$ is lowest bound for $A={\frac{1}{x}}$.
2. Now, suppose there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ we have $0+\epsilon<k$. That means $\varepsilon<k$. Take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{k+1}$

I need to improve my answer, but I don’t know how to follow.

Comment: If you can't use the Archimedean property, what *can* you use? Is your $x$ a real number? What properties (or definition) of real numbers do you have?

Comment: Do you have axiom of completeness? Or the least upper bound property?

Comment: @karl All untill completeness

Comment: "All until" doesn't mean anything if we don't have your textbook or whatever.

Comment: Assume you have an $x>0$ such that all $1/n\geq x$ for $n$ natural. Consider the set $I$ of all such $x$. These elements are called infinitesimals. We are assuming $I$ is non-empty. Let $s=\sup(I)$. Now $s\geq x>0$ and since $s\geq s$ we get $2s> s$. So, there is $n$ natural such that $1/n< 2s$. Then $1/(2n)\leq s$. But now, since  $s/2<s$, then $s/2$ should be infinitesimal. But $1/(4n)<s/2$. Contradiction.

Comment: @karl [Elementary Real Analysis](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/Elementary-Real-Analysis.php)

Comment: The way you started proof wouldn't get you to a contradiction, because $1/x$ isn't bounded above, so in fact you'd get that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $x>0$ such that $1/x>n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it correctly, you are allowed to use the greatest lower bound property. If this is the case, you can proceed as follows. Since $0$ is a lower bound for the set $A := \{1/n \mid n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}\}$, we conclude that $\inf(A) = 0$. Indeed, suppose otherwise that $L = \inf(A) > 0$. Consequently, $2L > L > 0$, whence one deduces there exists $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$ such that $2L > 1/n_{0}$, that is to say, $L > 1/2n_{0}$, which is a contradiction since $L = \inf(A)$.

Based on such result, we can solve the proposed exercise. Indeed, if $x > 0 = \inf(A)$, there exists $1/n\in A$ such that $x > 1/n$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you friend!

Comment: @RicardoMejíasConstanzo you are welcome! I am glad to help.